# Get Last Value in table

Tags: database

I want get the last value for determine column 
for example in this table

 id      name 
 1         Samer
 2         Fahd
 3         Hames
 4         fuad

I want get only last name  "fuad"  in sqlserver

all thanks

Answer (score 1):

Order by `ID` descending and `select top 1 name`:

```
select top 1 Name from MyTable order by ID desc
```

Comment: thank you Athon
but if the data no ordered by Id I want get the last value 
in any ordered for any field
all thanks for help